# SVG inside object tag causing height gap

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to add three SVG icons via object tag and this is my code.

```
<object data="/images/v3/notification-normal.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Now every time my page gets loaded this is what I get for a couple of seconds. (see screenshot)

[image]

It seems that something is causing height problem while rendering SVG icons or something. I can only see 3 dots and this is full svg icons when page is loaded.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Please include an [mcve].